# Chrome with the same version of Webkit as Safari

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, version, chromium

I am testing my web application in Safari 5.1.7 on Windows (the latest version available). It shows a specific bug which I want to verify in Chrome that is using the same version of Webkit as Safari 5.1.7. How can I find out which Chrome version I need to download?

From Wikipedia page about [Safari versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history) I know that Safari version 5.1.7 uses Webkit in version 534.57.2, but I can't seem to be able to translate that version to the corresponding Chrome version.

I found this post: [Which version of Webkit in a given Chrome release?](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/KBFLm28ncPE), but it doesn't quite help because it only gives the version of Webkit in a given Chrome release, not the version of Chrome that contains a given Webkit version.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do in this case is look at this [list of chrome user agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Chrome) and match to the closest webkit version, but it's tricky because you'll never get a full match.

For the sake of your specific questions, to get close to Safari 5.1.7's webkit engine you'd want to get a copy of the last Chrome 12 version. Technically Webkit 534.57.2 is somewhere between Chrome 13.0.766.0 and Chrome 13.0.782.1. But given that it's already hard to find old copies of Chrome. Finding an old very specific version like that on the web is near impossible.

Another great reference to find equivalent browser versions by date is the [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) date relative data.

Look up any feature (such as 'flexbox') and click on "Date Relative" for a visual comparison of all browser versions by date releases.

Comment: Thanks, another useful resource. Not sure it's enough to mark it as an answer. Maybe some time later if no one comes with a better idea?